# React native web send an email

Tags: reactjs, react-native-web

I'm trying to set a function where when a button is clicked the program will send an email. I'm using react native web. so far I have tried react-native-mail. this opens an email client but when I try to run build-web, the node module for react-native-mail can't be minified. I've also tried react-native-communications but I get an error as well. Are there any methods I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-mail` is a **native module**. As in `react-native-web`, you are running javascript code in the browser environment. It's not possible to run native code in the browser.

In this case, I'd suggest you write a specific component for web browser, and create an `<a>` element with a [`mailto:` href attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#E-mail_links) to invoke the system email client.